Add email as azure blob contributor using python sdk
I have email id from user and I would like to give them as azure blob container contributor roles using Python SDK. I have tried with this method but seems DefaultAzureCredientials is not working.
import os
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.storage import StorageManagementClient

# Set your Azure subscription ID, resource group name, storage account name, and container name
subscription_id = 'your_subscription_id'
resource_group_name = 'your_resource_group_name'
storage_account_name = 'your_storage_account_name'
container_name = 'your_container_name'
email_address = 'user@example.com'  # The email address to which you want to grant access

# Authenticate using DefaultAzureCredential
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

# Create clients
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
storage_client = StorageManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

# Get the storage account ID
storage_account = storage_client.storage_accounts.get_properties(resource_group_name, storage_account_name)
storage_account_id = storage_account.id

# Define the role assignment parameters
role_definition_id = "/subscriptions/{}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/{}".format(
    subscription_id,
    "b2e1d0c4-5f1b-4b6b-a1c1-4a2d5f8f3e56"  # Storage Blob Data Contributor role ID
)

# Create the role assignment
role_assignment_name = str(uuid.uuid4())  # Generate a unique GUID for the role assignment
role_assignment_parameters = {
    'properties': {
        'roleDefinitionId': role_definition_id,
        'principalId': email_address  # This should be the object ID of the user, not the email
    }
}

# Assign the role
role_assignment = resource_client.role_assignments.create(
    scope=storage_account_id,
    role_assignment_name=role_assignment_name,
    parameters=role_assignment_parameters
)

print(f"Role assignment created: {role_assignment.id}")`




I have email id from user and I would like to give them as azure blob container contributor roles using Python SDK. I have tried with this method but seems DefaultAzureCredientials is not working.

According to this MS-Document.
To assign Azure roles, you must have Role Based Access Control Administrator or User Access Administrator.
After assigning, you can assign the roleStorage blob data contributor role to the storage account container by user using below python code.
Code:
import os
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.authorization import AuthorizationManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.storage import StorageManagementClient
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient
import uuid
import asyncio

subscription_id = 'xxxxx'
resource_group_name = 'xxxxg'
storage_account_name = 'xxxx'
container_name = 'xxx'
email_address = 'xxxxxxonmicrosoft.com'

# Authenticate using DefaultAzureCredential
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

# Create clients
resource_client = AuthorizationManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
storage_client = StorageManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]

graph_client = GraphServiceClient(credential,scopes=scopes)

async def get_user_details():
    user_details = await graph_client.users.by_user_id(email_address).get()
    return user_details

async def main():
    user_details = await get_user_details()
    user_id = user_details.id
    return user_id

if __name__ == "__main__":
    user_id = asyncio.run(main())
    print(user_id)

    container_id="/subscriptions/{}/resourceGroups/{}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{}/blobServices/default/containers/{}".format(subscription_id,resource_group_name,storage_account_name,container_name)

    # Define the role assignment parameters
    role_definition_id = "/subscriptions/{}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/{}".format(
        subscription_id,
        "ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe" # Storage Blob Data Contributor role ID
    )

    role_assignment_parameters = {
        'properties': {
            'roleDefinitionId': role_definition_id,
            "principalType": "User",
            'principalId': user_id
        }
    }
    role_assignment_name = str(uuid.uuid4()) 
    role_assignment = resource_client.role_assignments.create(scope=container_id,
    role_assignment_name=role_assignment_name,
    parameters=role_assignment_parameters
)

print(f"Role assignment created: {role_assignment.id}")

Output:
xxxxxxc7ecb0bcd596
Role assignment created: /subscriptions/15xxx48f/resourceGroups/venkatesan-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/venkat891/blobServices/default/containers/test/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/ef8a22e4-bxxxx298c58


Portal:

Reference:
Role Assignments - Create - REST API (Azure Authorization) | Microsoft Learn
